# How to have a varibale amount of capturing groups in a regex expression?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am attempting to parse a basic math expression into groups with regex. For example:

`12+34-4.5`
Should have 5 groups, 3 operands and 2 operators

This is what I have so far:
`/(?:(\d+(?:\.\d)*)([+\-*/]{1}))+(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)/g`

But it only returns the last three groups.

Comment: It's not possible with regular expressions. The number of capturing groups is simply the number of `(...)` in the regexp.

Comment: If you use .Net regex, you can use `Captures` which will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To match the whole string you could use this regex

```
^[+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[+*\/\-]+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$
```

Start with an integer or decimal
`^[+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
Followed by 0 or more groups of sign(s) and an integer or decimal
`(?:[+*\/\-]+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$`

To capture explicitly 3 operands and 2 operators into 5 groups :

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([+*\/\-]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([+*\/\-]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

Notice that the `/` is also escaped with a backslash.

Test on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/WMjH2v/2)

Or perhaps match either a number or an operator

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[+*\/\-]+)
```